# BasicNameValuePair maximum value length? can i pass base64 string?

Tags: android, bitmap, base64, nvp

what is the maximum length i can pass in basicnamevaluepair?

i am passing a bytearray converted into a base64 string

but the string is truncated.

any suggestion or help will be much appreciated .

been stucked for days.

Comment: are you using get or post method?

Comment: iam using post method

Comment: How did you check that the string is truncated? And where?

Comment: It should not get truncated at all . I have sent before successfully

Comment: OP did not tell if the truncation was on receiving or sending side.

Comment: if(params != null) {
               for (NameValuePair nvp : params) {
                Log.v("tag", "PostParams: " + nvp.getValue());
               }
              }

i have this log in my service call i tried a hard coded string which is smaller than the actual image but still i get a truncated one

Comment: Log statement does not print all of big strings. There is a limit on what gets printed. Better determine length of the strings before and after.

Comment: okay thank you so much. i guess what i am passing is not the issue maybe it is on the receiving side. ill have to check that thank you again